# App crashing on MiniControllerFragment inflate

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk, android-cast-api

I have added MiniControllerFrament in XML of mainActivity, whenever the app launch it crashes with the below log (Testing this on Google Pixel 4a device)

```
2022-01-27 20:06:08.063 21050-21050/? E/AndroidRuntime:     
        at com.vuclip.viu.CastMiniController.onCreateView(CastMiniController.kt:11)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2995)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:388)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:260)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:241)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1065)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:663)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
        at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@20.1.0:2)
        at com.vuclip.viu.CastMiniController.onCreateView(CastMiniController.kt:11)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2995)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:388)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:260)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:241)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1065)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:663)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
        at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@20.1.0:2)
        at com.vuclip.viu.CastMiniController.onCreateView(CastMiniController.kt:11)
```